# Angular, drawing multiples rectangles with canvas on mouse event

Tags: angular, html5-canvas, mouseevent, rectangles

I'm trying to create a drawing tool with angular. I created a tool that you can draw a rectangle on a canvas element, the tool is working ok, but I can only draw one rectangle at a time, I just can't figure out how to "not clear" the previous rectangle and keep multiples drawings on my canvas. I cannot clear many canvas because i'm gonna have more drawings, not just rectangles.

```
rectangleDrawing() {

    // first coordinates when clicked
    let startX = 0;
    let startY = 0;

    const rect = this.canvasEl.getBoundingClientRect();

    fromEvent(this.canvasEl, "mousedown")
        .pipe(
            switchMap((e:MouseEvent) => {

                startX = e.clientX - rect.left;
                startY = e.clientY - rect.top;

                return fromEvent(this.canvasEl, 'mousemove').pipe(

                    takeUntil(fromEvent(this.canvasEl, 'mouseup')),
                    takeUntil(fromEvent(this.canvasEl, 'mouseleave'))
                )

            })
        ).subscribe((event:MouseEvent) => {

            let x = event.clientX - rect.left;
            let y = event.clientY - rect.top;

            let width = x - startX;
            let height = y - startY;


            this.setCanvasProperties(10, 'square', 'rgba(255,158,43,0.6)');

            this.cx.beginPath();

            // if I comment this line, the rectangles will stay, but they 
            // won't be clear, making multiples rectangles inside the 
            // main rectangle
            this.cx.clearRect(0,0, this.canvasEl.width, this.canvasEl.height);

            this.cx.rect(startX, startY, width, height);

            this.cx.stroke();

        });

}

setCanvasProperties(lineWidth, lineCap, strokeStyle) {
    this.cx = this.canvasEl.getContext('2d');
    this.cx.lineWidth = lineWidth;
    this.cx.lineCap = lineCap;
    this.cx.strokeStyle = strokeStyle;
}
```

This link is a good example: https://jsfiddle.net/richardcwc/ukqhf54k/, if you comment the clear line, you can see main problem. Many examples seems to permit only one rectangle at a time.

Comment: I am facing the same problem like you man!! I saw your code and yes if we comment the clear line we can't draw multiple rectangles.. Please let me know if you found any solution as I am stuck. (The below solution which was given by Garcia is  not in Angular)

Comment: But when you first time trying to create the rectangle it won't work but after from second attempt the rectangle is drawn. Always on the first attempt it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On mouse up, you could store the drawn rect in an array, and then draw that array and the current rect.

First, lets set the array and keep the width and height as a global variable:

```
var width;
var height;
var drawItems = [];
```

Then, the `mouseup` function will be like this:

```
$(canvas).on('mouseup', function(e) {
  mousedown = false;

  drawItems.push({
    x0: last_mousex,
    x1: width,
    y0: last_mousey,
    y1: height
  });
});
```

And this is the `mousemove` function:

```
$(canvas).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousex = parseInt(e.clientX-canvasx);
    mousey = parseInt(e.clientY-canvasy);
    if(mousedown) {
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); //clear canvas

        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 10;

        for(var i=0; i<drawItems.length; i++) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(drawItems[i].x0, drawItems[i].y0, drawItems[i].x1, drawItems[i].y1);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        width = mousex-last_mousex;
        height = mousey-last_mousey;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(last_mousex,last_mousey,width,height);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    //Output
    $('#output').html('current: '+mousex+', '+mousey+'<br/>last: '+last_mousex+', '+last_mousey+'<br/>mousedown: '+mousedown);
});
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/u60mxz49/) is the updated fiddle

I hope it helps

Comment: I was also facing the same issue like @heliosk . My code is in Angular but I have applied the logic you suggested. Thanks for the suggestion, it fixed my issue.